# Split rows to multiple line based on comma : one liner solution

Tags: awk, sed

I want to split the following format to unique lines

**Input:**

```
17:79412041:C:T,CGGATGTCAT
17:79412059:C:G,T
17:79412138:G:A,C
17:79412192:C:G,T,A
```

**Desired output**

```
17:79412041:C:T
17:79412041:C:CGGATGTCAT
17:79412059:C:G
17:79412059:C:T
17:79412138:G:A
17:79412138:G:C
17:79412192:C:G
17:79412192:C:T
17:79412192:C:A
```

Basically split the input to unique rows or firstID:secondID:thirdID:FourthID. Here multiple row may have firstID:secondID:thirdID may be common and the FourthID is the one it make each raw unique(that was seperated by "," in the input).

Thanks in advance
Shams

Comment: `new to coding` see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info ... this forum is not a free coding service.. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: There are few things as guaranteed to produce a look of disgust from the regulars here than insisting the solution must be a "one liner". If cramming as many characters as possible onto 1 line is in any way important to you then you do have a lot to learn....

Comment: @Sundeep, I have edited my post for "your problem part" and I guess that may make you happy!(not being so personal). And I guess your statement may be an insult to those cool guys down there to this post who came up with fantastic solutions, by the time you took for finding a complaint about how I pose the question!...

Comment: it wasn't a complaint.. rather few suggestions from my side in trying to help... up to you to go through those links or to ignore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** one-liner

```
$ awk -F":" '{gsub(/,/,":"); a=$1FS$2FS$3; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) print a FS $i;}' f1
17:79412041:C:T
17:79412041:C:CGGATGTCAT
17:79412059:C:G
17:79412059:C:T
17:79412138:G:A
17:79412138:G:C
17:79412192:C:G
17:79412192:C:T
17:79412192:C:A
```

We are first replacing all `,` with `:` to keep a common delimiter i.e. `:`

We are then traversing from 4th field to end and printing each field by prefixing first three fields.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner here:

```
$ awk -F':' '{ split($4,a,","); for (i in a) { print $1":"$2":"$3":"a[i] } }' data.txt
```

Produces:

```
17:79412041:C:T
17:79412041:C:CGGATGTCAT
17:79412059:C:G
17:79412059:C:T
17:79412138:G:A
17:79412138:G:C
17:79412192:C:G
17:79412192:C:T
17:79412192:C:A
```

Explanation:

```
split(string, array, delimiter)
```

splits the string by the delimiter, and saves the pieces into the array.

The for-in loop simply prints every piece in the array with the first three entries.

The `-F':'` part defines the top-level delimiter.

Comment: any work around on if a second column exists that need to be printed along with it

Comment: `17:79412041:C:T,CGGATGTCAT pass;no_artifact
17:79412059:C:G,T pass;no_artifact
17:79412138:G:A,C fail;low_cov
17:79412192:C:G,T,A pass;high_mapq`

Comment: with the above command its printing only with the last split `17:79412041:C:T
17:79412041:C:CGGATGTCAT pass;no_artifact
17:79412059:C:G
17:79412059:C:T pass;no_artifact
17:79412138:G:A
17:79412138:G:C fail;low_cov
17:79412192:C:G
17:79412192:C:T
17:79412192:C:A pass;high_mapq`

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`, should work for any number of fields

```
$ awk -F: '{split($NF,a,","); for(i in a) {sub($NF"$",a[i]); print}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` + `gsub` of it may help you on same too:

```
awk -F":" '{gsub(",",ORS $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 "&");gsub(/,/,":")} 1' OFS=":"   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\(\(.*:\)[^:,]*\),/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Insert a newline and the key for each comma in a line.

An alternative using a loop and syntactic sugar:

```
sed -r ':a;s/^((.*:)[^:,]*),/\1\n\2/;ta' file
```